# How to view IIS failed request log on Win 11

Tags: iis, windows-11

Win 11 provides only Edge anymore, what is the best way to view the IIS failed request log files without Internet Explorer?

Comment: by Event Viewer can see all request

Comment: @Dashrath are you using Windows? Did you read failed request tracing in Event Viewer? Then you should post detailed steps and screenshots as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 11 OS, you could try to use [Edge IE mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/internet-explorer-mode-in-microsoft-edge-6604162f-e38a-48b2-acd2-682dbac6f0de) to view the Failed Request Tracing logs.

IE mode uses the IE browser engine to load the page in the Edge browser.

You could follow the steps below.

1. Launch the Edge browser.
2. Add the file path in the address bar and press Enter.
   [image]
3. From Settings and More (denoted by ...), Select option **Reload in Internet Explorer mode**.
   [image]
4. Failed Request Tracing log will be loaded.
   [image]

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this menu entry below "Read Aloud", probably a company policy that IE mode is not offered anymore?

Comment: You could type `edge://policy/` in the Edge address bar and press Enter key. It will show you the policy list set by your organization. You need to check for the policy `InternetExplorerIntegrationReloadInIEModeAllowed` is disabled? If you don't found this policy then you could request the IT department to enabled this policy. It may help you add the option in the Edge browser.

Comment: To enable this setting, navigate to `edge://settings/defaultbrowser`, Slide the Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer toggle to ON and restart Edge. [source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/internet-explorer-mode-in-microsoft-edge-6604162f-e38a-48b2-acd2-682dbac6f0de)

Answer (score -3):

Can't this be done with the logfiles of Windows it self through the Event Viewer?

Right-click on the Start button and select "Event Viewer".

Comment: You should give that a try to see if you can magically get it working.

Answer (score -3):

Open event viewer

under Window log

Application

It will show like in error section:

[image]